# Haskell greedy elem?

Tags: haskell

I love to use elem in haskell for catching IP:Port. However elem is "exact match", and I cannot find a way to split with : as delimiter? Any idea to work around this?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

Use `break`:

```
Prelude> break (==':') "192.168.0.1:5000"
("192.168.0.1",":5000")
Prelude> break (==':') "192.168.0.15"
("192.168.0.15","")
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like the [split package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.4.2/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asepBy)

```
bash> cabal update && cabal install split
bash> ghci
ghci> import Data.List.Split
ghci> splitOn ":" "192.168.0.1:9000"
["192.168.0.1","9000"]
```